# How to make this method print messages in real-time?

Tags: rust, terminal, command-line

I create a `CmdRunner` struct to handle commands' input and output:

```
use std::{io::Write, process::Command};

pub struct CmdRunner {
    pub command: std::process::Command,
}

impl CmdRunner {
    pub fn new(command_string: &str, input: Option<&str>) -> CmdRunner {
        let mut command = Command::new("script");

        if let Some(input_str) = input {
            command
                .arg("-qec")
                .arg(command_string.replace("{}", input_str));
        } else {
            command.arg("-qec").arg(command_string);
        }

        command.arg("/dev/null");

        CmdRunner { command }
    }

    pub fn execute(&mut self, stdout: &mut impl Write) {
        let output = self.command.output();

        match output {
            Ok(output) => {
                if output.status.success() {
                    let stdout_str = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout);

                    for line in stdout_str.lines() {
                        write!(stdout, "{}\r\n", line).unwrap();
                    }
                } else {
                    let stdout_str = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout);
                    let stderr_str = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr);

                    write!(stdout, "\r\n").unwrap();
                    write!(stdout, "Exit status: {}\r\n", output.status).unwrap();
                    write!(stdout, "Standard error: {}\r\n", stderr_str.trim()).unwrap();
                    write!(stdout, "Standard output: {}\r\n", stdout_str.trim()).unwrap();
                }
            }
            Err(e) => {
                write!(stdout, "Error executing command: {:?}\r\n", e).unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine. However, for example, if the command to run is this:

```
python3 script.py
```

And the contents of `script.py` is this:

```py
import time
print('a')
time.sleep(10)
print('b')
time.sleep(10)
```

`'a'` and `'b'` won't be printed in the terminal in real-time. They will be printed after the command has been executed.

How to modify this code so that messages are printed in the terminal in real time? Just like when you execute scripts directly in the terminal?

Comment: The easiest way is to inherit the output instead of capturing it. Do you have a requirement of capturing the output?

Comment: The output method of Command struct waits for the command to complete before returning its output. `spawn` method on the otherh and can be used to capture the command output in real-time: by creating a child process and then use the stdout field of the Child struct to read the output as it is generated.

Comment: @JishanShaikh Could you post an answer with a little example of this?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman No, I just want to be able to run the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason I suspect is that the printed stdout values are buffered at execution time.

One way we can do this by using `command.spawn()` instead of `command.output()` to create another thread to handle the printing. Like this [**playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ca838147d4ff62084c028edd69da71e2) and code here:

```rust
use std::{
    io::{BufRead, BufReader, Write},
    process::{Command, Stdio},
};

pub struct CmdRunner {
    pub command: std::process::Command,
}

impl CmdRunner {
    pub fn new(command_string: &str, input: Option<&str>) -> CmdRunner {
        let mut command = Command::new("script");

        if let Some(input_str) = input {
            command
                .arg("-qec")
                .arg(command_string.replace("{}", input_str));
        } else {
            command.arg("-qec").arg(command_string);
        }

        command.arg("/dev/null");

        CmdRunner { command }
    }

    pub fn execute(&mut self, stdout: &mut impl Write) {
        self.command.stdout(Stdio::piped());
        self.command.stderr(Stdio::piped());

        let mut child = self.command.spawn().expect("failed to spawn command");

        let stdout_pipe = child.stdout.take().unwrap();
        let stderr_pipe = child.stderr.take().unwrap();

        let stdout_reader = BufReader::new(stdout_pipe);
        let stderr_reader = BufReader::new(stderr_pipe);

        let stdout_thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
            for line in stdout_reader.lines() {
                if let Ok(line) = line {
                    println!("{}", line);
                }
            }
        });

        let stderr_thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
            for line in stderr_reader.lines() {
                if let Ok(line) = line {
                    eprintln!("{}", line);
                }
            }
        });

        let status = child.wait().expect("failed to wait for command");

        stdout_thread.join().expect("failed to join stdout thread");
        stderr_thread.join().expect("failed to join stderr thread");

        if status.success() {
            write!(stdout, "Command executed successfully\r\n").unwrap();
        } else {
            write!(stdout, "Command failed with exit code {}\r\n", status.code().unwrap_or(-1)).unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

**For Python specific solutions:**

If buffering stdouts is the actual problem we are facing, we can also use `PYTHONBUFFERED` environment variable before calling the `Command::new` in CmdRunner struct:

```
command.env("PYTHONUNBUFFERED", "1");
```

Also, may be unrelated, Python provides `flush` parameter to print function to avoid buffering stdout values:

```py
print('a', flush=True)
```

Without editing Python or Rust code here, the Python3's `-u` flag also exists to 'unbuffer' output.

```py
python3 -u script.py
```

I suppose it can also be achieved by `stdbuf` or `unbuffer` commands.

Comment: Wow, as a Rust beginner, that's a lot to absorb. But it worked, thanks! I'll study your code line by line.